# Why am i getting failure to find com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT error when i run mvn -DskipTests -Dgpg.skip=true install and how to solve it?

Tags: maven, zxing

When i try to run

```
 mvn -DskipTests -Dgpg.skip=true install
```

then i get following error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.7:copy (copy-android) on project core: Unable to find artifact. Failure to find com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
 [ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.zxing -DartifactId=core -Dversion=2.2-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
 [ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.google.zxing -DartifactId=core -Dversion=2.2-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
 [ERROR] sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true),
 [ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I went to https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots but didn't find `com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.2-SNAPSHOT`.

Any idea how can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 2.2-SNAPSHOT. 2.2 has been released. You either mean 2.2, or 2.3-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: look at the error log in question. It says 2.2-SNAPSHOT. Anyways what should i do to solve it?

Comment: Exactly. Your pom.xml refers to it, but it doesn't exist in the repo. Depend on version 2.2.

Comment: So what should i do? change pom.xml? or something else?

Comment: any ideas which lines should i change? I am new with zxing so please write down lines i should edit. Thanks

Comment: Well, did you search for the string "2.2-SNAPSHOT" in the file? this really couldn't be simpler!